# Model/View: meaning of shared selection

Tags: c++, design-patterns, qt4

Here is a simple example that demonstrates selection that shared between multiple views.

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication qApplication(argc, argv);
    QWidget qWidget;

    QStringListModel qStringListModel;
    qStringListModel.setStringList(QStringList()
                                   << "Item1"
                                   << "Item2"
                                   << "Item3"
                                   << "Item4"
                                   << "Item5"
                                   << "Item6"
                                  );

    QTreeView* pTreeView = new QTreeView;
    pTreeView->setModel(&qStringListModel);

    QListView* pListView = new QListView;
    pListView->setModel(&qStringListModel);

    QTableView* pTableView = new QTableView;
    pTableView->setModel(&qStringListModel);

    QItemSelectionModel qItemSelectionModel(&qStringListModel);
    pTreeView->setSelectionModel(&qItemSelectionModel);
    pListView->setSelectionModel(&qItemSelectionModel);
    pTableView->setSelectionModel(&qItemSelectionModel);

    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(pTreeView);
    layout->addWidget(pListView);
    layout->addWidget(pTableView);
    qWidget.setLayout(layout);

    qWidget.show();

    return qApplication.exec();
}
```

[image]

I do not quite understand for why this is necessary and when it can be useful?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: This seems off-topic for Stack Overflow - it's not a question about a programming problem.  If you ever see a use for it, you'll know how to do it.  If you never see a use for it, you'll never use it.

Comment: If you want to remove this content, there should be a "delete" link next to the "edit" link. (Questions which have upvoted answers etc won't be eligible for deletion, though.) Please stop vandalizing your posts.